# Approach to implementing an AJAX queue

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, queue

- jQuery 2.0.3

I want to fire off an AJAX call when data changes in an edit input control. I realise I can do this via the onChange event. However if the user enters: 123 I don't want to fire the AJAX 3 times.

Instead I want to wait for a "setting period" and then fire off the call. The setting period gets reset each time the control changes. So the idea being as I type 123 quickly, some time passes (settling) and I make the AJAX call.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to implement this with jQuery? Are there any constructs I can use in jQuery to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to throttle the event with a timeout

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    var self = this;

    clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );

    $(this).data('timer', 
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url  : 'someurl.php',
                data : self.value
            });
        }, 500)
    )
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy way is with setTimeout / clearTimeout on the change event:

```
var timeout = null;
$('input').bind('keyup blur', function() {
    if (timeout !== null) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {

        // Make your ajax request here

    }, 300);
});
```

Change the 300 to number of milliseconds you want to have to wait before the ajax request is made.

Comment: The `change` event "fires when the user blurs the input AND the text has been changed since the last focus." ([source](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html)) It won't fire on any key event. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Jt5V/embedded/result/)

Comment: @Trojan - Thanks, you're right - just typed it off the top of my head and wasn't thinking right. Updated to bind to blur and keyup events.

Comment: Also, you need to assign the result of `setTimeout` to `timeout`, or it will never be changed from `null`.

Comment: Thanks again - I should make it a point to test my answers a bit more before posting.